# Magento - Different homepage for mobile vs. desktop

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system, magento-1.7

Pretty straightforward question: How do I pull a different cms page for the homepage of a magento website for the mobile version of the site versus the desktop version? I'm currently pulling the different themes based on user agent via System -> Configuration -> General/Web.

I've tried this tutorial, to no avail: http://www.magemetro.com/blog/How-To-Mobilize-Your-Magento-Site-for-iPhone-Android-Mobile-Commerce/

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on designing 2 separate sites (1 for mobile and 1 for desktop), then you may want to just create a separate store view. This will allow you to have a different configuration for each store (meaning you can choose a different design package and theme for your mobile store view).

This means that you can have different templates for each store and anytime you create a CMS page or static block, you can specify which store view it applies to, or apply it globally.